# Finding the span of this mapping in P2

Tags: linear-algebra

I have managed to do 10 a&b but im stuck on part C, i understand i have to form a span using Po +P1x+P2x^2 but im not sure what to do next, i have an exam later this week and I have also looked through my notes and tried finding a similar answer online but no luck. Much help would be appreciated. [image: 10C]

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: $T(p)=p(0)+p(1)=0\Rightarrow p(0)=-p(1)$. This should help in determining the dimension of the kernel of $T$.